# Product edit form savebutton is not working in magento backend

Tags: backend, magento2.3.1, console, product-edit

Steps to reproduce.

```
1.Go backend -> Catalog -> Products

2.Edit and save the product

3.While clicking the save button throws console error like below
```

[image]

Can anypone please guide me and solve my issue.

Comment: check this one a number greater than 0 in this field.
Quantity => Advanced Inventory =>  Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart